# Conflicting errors: "setting an array element with a sequence," "Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray)"

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I apologize as I know there are several answered questions regarding each of these individual error messages, but I haven't found an answer for one that doesn't cause the other.

I am trying to train a convolutional neural network to determine whether or not the cryptopunk images have earrings or not. I have the following code to set things up after loading all the libraries:

```
imgURL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/larvalabs/cryptopunks/master/punks.png"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(imgURL, "cryptoPunksAll.jpg")

img = PIL.Image.open("cryptoPunksAll.jpg").convert("RGB")
img

img.size

imgArray = np.asarray(img)

finalArray = np.empty((24, 24, 3, 10000))
for i in range(100):
  for j in range(100):
    a, b = 24 * i, 24 * (i + 1)
    c, d = 24 * j, 24 * (j + 1)
    idx = j + i * 100
    finalArray[:, :, :, idx] = imgArray[a:b, c:d, :]

for i in range(10000):
    datArray[i] = finalArray[:, :, :, i]

baseUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cryptopunksnotdead/punks/master/"
for i in range(0,10000,1000):
  url = baseUrl+str(i)+"-"+str(i + 999)+".csv"
  print(url)
  if (i == 0):
    dat = pd.read_csv(url)
  else :
    dat = pd.concat ([dat, pd.read_csv(url)],
                     join = 'inner',
                     ignore_index = True)

dat = dat.assign(earring = (dat[' accessories'].str.find("Earring") > 0) * 1)

datArray = datArray/255
x = datArray
y = dat.earring
image_train, image_test, earring_train, earring_test = tts(x, y, test_size = 0.33)

# set up model
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(24, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(24, 24, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(48, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(48, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(48, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10))

# compile model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
# fit model
fit = model.fit(image_train, earring_train, epochs=10,
                    validation_data = (image_test, earring_test))
```

When I run the code, compile, and fit the model, I get the "Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray)" error. If I try to fix this by converting to different data types, (eg `x = np.asarray(x).astype('float32')` or `x = np.asarray(x).astype(np.float32)`) I get the "setting an array element with a sequence" error because each element of the array is an image, not a number. I got much of this code from https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/cnn, so I know it works with images, but the training and test datasets are already set up in every example I can find, so I haven't been able to view an example of setting up training and test datasets of images to avoid this issue. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Images all have to have the same `shape`

Comment: Check the `dtype` and `shape` after doing `y=np.asarray(x)`.  If it is 1d and object dtype, then `tensorflow` will have problems making a `Tensor`.  That's your first error.  You should have shown the Traceback.  When you try `astype`, that produces the second error.  And for essentially the same reason - `x` does not contain identically shaped images.